# Bootstrap icons does not appear in the front-end when used in Vuejs Template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I am trying to build the Web application using the `Vue.JS` and within my application, I am trying to use the `[Bootstrap Icons][1]`. But for some reason even after adding the icons, they do not appear on the screen.

I did the following steps:

1. Install `Bootstrap Icons` into the application:

```
npm install bootstrap-icons
```

After installing I am able to see it in my `package.json` file.

2. Add it to `Main.js` file:

```
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
```

3. Within the component add it to the required button:

```
<template>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary copy" @click="copyXML()">Copy<i class="bi bi-clipboard"></i></button>
</template>
```

This is not making any difference to my button text. I am still able to see only `Copy` text on the button.

As per the documentation, there is another way to add icons. When I add the `SVG` then I get the icons:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary copy" @click="copyXML()">Copy<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-archive" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1v7.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.5 2.5h-9A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 1 12.5V5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2zm2 3v7.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 14h9a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V5H2zm13-3H1v2h14V2zM5 7.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg></button>
```

I am not understanding why only `SVG` works, isn't it possible to add only `<i class="bi bi-clipboard"></i>` and get the icons?

This may be a silly question but I am looking for some explanation and usage of icons in the Vuejs application.

Comment: It seems like the font with the icons is missing. Open the Network tab and check if the font loaded

Comment: @Vadzim Hi Thanks a lot for looking into the issue and providing the response. `Font With Icons` missing means? Do I need to install any new package? If so can you please specify which one I need to install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find the work-around. Most of the `npm` packages do not support `Vuejs 3.x` as it has been recently released.

The workaround is not to install it as a `npm library` rather than including the direct `js` or as `CDN link` to our application.

I added the following `CDN` to my `index.html` and that worked for me :

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Icons Starts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Icons Ends -->
```

Answer (score 49):

Adding this line to the main.js seems to work for me:

```
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'
```

The important part seems to be the .css at the end.  Without it, it imports the .js file with the same name.

Now the i tags are working:

```
<i class="bi bi-clipboard"></i>
```

Comment: This is the best and cleanest answer in my opinion. (Note the question is tagged `vuejs2` but the OP's answer refers to `Vuejs3`.  As of 2022/11, Vue 3 and Bootstrap 5 function just fine together.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import bootstrap-icons.css file in the main.js file:

```
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
```